# SOAP WSDL works only one operation

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have soap client and soap server written in PHP:

**Server.php**

```
// Initializing code is omitted

$server = new SoapServer('http://wsdl.localhost:8888/calculator_service.wsdl');
$server->setClass('CalculatorGateway');
$server->handle();
```

**Client.php**

```
// Initializing code is omitted

$request = new Request();
$request->data = new DataObject();
$request->data->sourceValue = 10;
$request->data->modifyBy = 5;

$client = new SoapClient(
    'http://wsdl.localhost:8888/calculator_service.wsdl',
    ['soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'classmap' => [
        'Response' => 'Response'
    ]]
);

// $argv[1] must be one of "add" or "sub"
$response = $client->$argv[1]($request);
echo 'Result: ' . $response->result;
```

**WSDL**:

```
<definitions ...>
<types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
               xmlns:tns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               targetNamespace="http://wsdl.localhost:8888/">

        <xs:complexType name="DataObject">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="sourceValue" type="xs:double" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="modifyBy" type="xs:double" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:element name="Request">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="data" type="DataObject" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="Response">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="result" type="xs:double" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
</types>

<message name="addRequest">
    <part name="Request" element="tns:Request" />
</message>
<message name="addResponse">
    <part name="Response" element="tns:Response" />
</message>

<message name="subRequest">
    <part name="Request" element="tns:Request" />
</message>
<message name="subResponse">
    <part name="Response" element="tns:Response" />
</message>

<portType name="CalculatorServicePortType">
    <operation name="add">
        <input message="tns:addRequest" />
        <output message="tns:addResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="sub">
        <input message="tns:subRequest" />
        <output message="tns:subResponse" />
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="CalculatorServiceBinding" type="tns:CalculatorServicePortType">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="add">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" />
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="sub">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" />
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>

<service name="CalculatorService">
    <port name="CalculatorServicePort" binding="tns:CalculatorServiceBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://wsdl.localhost:8888/CalculatorService.php" />
    </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

**My problem:** Whatever operatiom I'm requesting for, always the first one, which declared in binding section, will be executed. E.g. in this case, even if I'm requesting for "sub", "add" operation is executed. As an experement, I can change order like this:

```
<binding name="CalculatorServiceBinding" type="tns:CalculatorServicePortType">
    <operation name="sub">
    <!-- sub operation used to be on the second place -->
    </operation>

    <operation name="add">
    <!-- add operation used to be on the first place -->
    </operation>
</binding>
```

And now "sub" operation executes all the time.

What is the problem? Am I wrong with the binding section?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was very simple. **Style** attribute must be present in **soap:binding** element. Like this:

```
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
```